# Producing Pressurized Hydrogen Underwater Then Using it To Do Work

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation, hydrogen, renewable-energy

This is a bit of a weird one but I didn't know where else to ask this.

I was recently talking to my brother and he told me about an idea he had talked with his boss about how to create compressed hydrogen and also use it to do work in a somewhat renewable way. I was skeptical of his claims but I wasn't able to pinpoint where the system breaks down. I am an electrical engineer and have taken physics 1/2 but am a bit rusty on it so I just needed an actual physics explanation.

The idea is to bore a hole deep into the ocean or some other place to create a place where you could electrolyze water and then collect the resulting products in a balloon or other vessel. The gas would displace water in the vessel and you could then release it to float up to the surface. He then said to have it run up along a pole with windings and place a magnet on the vessel so it would generate electricity as it travels up to the surface. You could use this energy to electrolyze the water below again and have a second vessel to capture the products. Once at a predetermined depth below the surface, you could release the gas into a bigger holding vessel for use in hydrogen generators. The vessel would then float back down due to losing its bouyancy and generate electricity again as it falls.

My first thought was that the rising and falling vessels couldn't create enough electricity to do the electrolysis but they just proposed building it deeper so it would run longer and generate more electricity. I also wanted to say that the high pressure would affect the electroylsis but I just wasn't sure. This system goes against everything I know from Physics but I just can't see where it breaks down. Probably missing something simple.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Going deeper probably would not help, it would further compress the gasses giving less water displacement.

Comment: Do you think that electrolyzing water at surface pressure will require the same amount of energy as electrolyzing it to produce hydrogen and oxygen at much higher pressure?  What would be the change in Gibbs free energy for the two scenarios?

Answer (score 4):

As you suspected, this doesn't work because electrolyzing water is more difficult at high pressure.  According to [the Nernst equation](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/16%3A_Electrochemistry/16.04%3A_The_Nernst_Equation), the change in Gibbs free energy (and therefore the voltage required) for an electrochemical reaction depends on the concentrations of the reactants and products.  The concentration of a gas is measured by its partial pressure.  In this case, the reaction becomes more unfavorable at greater depth, because the concentration of water barely changes while the pressure of the product gases (hydrogen and oxygen) increases.

The same idea is also discussed in [this question on Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111491/pressure-dependence-of-electrolysis-voltage).

Comment: FWIW, [high-pressure electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pressure_electrolysis) can be a useful way to produce high-pressure hydrogen. Of course it does require more energy than low pressure electrolysis, but it's more energy-efficient than using a mechanical compressor. I suppose the tricky part is ensuring that you don't get any oxygen gas mixed with your hydrogen...